# Join and Grouping Results

Tags: sql-server, join, group-by, limit

Summary; Joining some of tables has similar results by some columns. How can we group them and select max(column).

My query is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1000) LG_070_ITEMS.CODE AS PRODCODE,
                LG_070_01_SERILOTN.CODE AS CODE,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.OUTCOST,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.LOGICALREF AS LREF,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.INSLTRANSREF,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.INVENNO,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.INTRANSREF,
                LG_070_01_SLTRANS.STTRANSREF
FROM LG_070_01_SERILOTN
INNER JOIN LG_070_01_SLTRANS ON LG_070_01_SLTRANS.SLREF = LG_070_01_SERILOTN.LOGICALREF
INNER JOIN LG_070_ITEMS ON LG_070_ITEMS.LOGICALREF = LG_070_01_SERILOTN.ITEMREF
WHERE [TIGERDB].[dbo].[LG_070_01_SERILOTN].CODE = '868328002749220'
```

And also answer from database is;

Prodcode code---------------COST--LREF ------one twho three four

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   46255------- 0    10    0   33584

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   46504-------    46255   10  33584   33639

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   46524-------    46504   11  33639   33640

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   51273-------    46524   11  33640   38581

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   51285-------    51273   9   38581   38587

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   52275-------    51273   11  38581   39823

K-3773  868328002749220 50,85   52276-------    52275   9   39823   39824

And now my problem is, how can i select last row. It can be bigger of LREF Column or column-one.

My queries are same. I am using numbers in where stuation and results are as same as this one.

I Tried to use max(columname) with group by othercolumns etc.
I used query designer with microsoft sql server management tool.

In that three table, non-selected columns are not important for me.With mysql i can do this with select ...max(lref) from ... joins ... group by code but i must do this with mssql.

Comment: Top 1000 is important because in my where, there is more then 1 expression. where code ='1' or code = '2'.. etc. And i need last row of that codes.

Answer (score 0):

Query (Probably will be expensive):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1000) t3.CODE AS PRODCODE,
                t.CODE AS CODE,
                t2.OUTCOST,
                t2.LOGICALREF AS LREF,
                t2.INSLTRANSREF,
                t2.INVENNO,
                t2.INTRANSREF,
                t2.STTRANSREF
FROM LG_070_01_SERILOTN t
INNER JOIN LG_070_01_SLTRANS t2 ON t2.SLREF = t.LOGICALREF
INNER JOIN LG_070_ITEMS t3 ON t3.LOGICALREF = t.ITEMREF
WHERE t.CODE = '868328002749220'
AND t2.LOGICALREF = (SELECT MAX(tt2.LOGICALREF)
                         FROM LG_070_01_SERILOTN tt
                         INNER JOIN LG_070_01_SLTRANS tt2 
                          ON tt2.SLREF = tt.LOGICALREF
                         INNER JOIN LG_070_ITEMS tt3 
                          ON tt3.LOGICALREF = tt.ITEMREF
                          WHERE tt.CODE = t.CODE)
```

Example query **[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12a7c/9)**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (1000) t.*
FROM Table1 t
WHERE t.LREF = (SELECT MAX(tt.LREF)
                FROM Table1 tt
                WHERE tt.CODE = t.CODE)
```

Result:

```
| PRODCODE |            CODE |  COST |  LREF |   ONE | TWHO | THREE |  FOUR |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   K-3773 | 868328002749220 | 50,85 | 52276 | 52275 |    9 | 39823 | 39824 |
```

Comment: I tried it with a one where expression it is okey but when i try where code='1' or code='2' first row is single line but second code's lines are 5lines. These codes are products. I want to select all products first bigger lines.

Comment: ok so second code all 5 lines got same LREF ? If yeas how to know what line it should return? Maybe doesn't matter, just return 1 line with max(LREF)?